# How do I merge two accounts?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have created an account on Stack Overflow created with my Wordpress login, and an email address ending in .co.uk. I have another account used on other Stack Exchange sites that use my Google account. I want to merge those accounts, and use Google for logging in.

I logged into Stack Overflow with my Wordpress account, changed the email address to my Google address, and tried to save (and thus merge), but got this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Email is already registered

Do you have any idea on what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Email team@stackoverflow.com and explain your problem.

Comment: From SO Team: While logged into one of your accounts, click the "my logins" link on your profile page. Then click "add more logins..." and log in with your other credentials (wordpress or gmail, whichever one isn't already listed on that account). Once done and both sets of credentials are showing up on the "my logins" pop-up, the system should merge

Comment: @Mark - You should put that comment in an answer (and accept it)